# Unable to view User Stories / Tasks under Sprint Board in a Inherited Agile board

Tags: azure, azure-boards, user-stories, backlog, sprint

In AzureDevOPS, I inherited a Agile board and created the Epic, Features, User Stories, Tasks etc. I created Sprints and moved respective Features into their respective Sprints. However, upon clicking Sprint board, I don't see the assigned features or user stories under Taskboard or Backlog option. It just asks me to add a Work Item again.

And when I click on the Boards>>Backlogg I can see the Iteration Path specified correctly.

Checked all the Project Settings, Org Settings, but unable to figure it out. However, another project in normal Agile workflow works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a Team set up, and you need to Select the iterations for the team. Having the iterations exist, and having them visible to a team are separately configurable.

[image]

Project configuration is where you **create** the area paths and iterations.

Team configuration is where you **select** the appropriate area paths and iterations for that specific team.

If there's only 1 team, it's just a select-all.